# How to fix a broken Adobe Air package?

Tags: dpkg, adobe-air, package-management

I'm using 64 bit version of Ubuntu 10.10 and have some problems with broken dependencies. I needed Adobe Air but it was not availble via apt-get, so I downloaded it from Adobe and installed. Then I succesfully installed adobe air application. It started and works pretty good. However when I start synaptic it claims that I have broken package (it is my adobe air application with some numbers attached). It says that this application requires adobeair package which can't be found in repositories and thus it can't be installed. But I have it and it works.

Do you know any workaround? For example how to tell dpkg that I have adobeair installed, or how to remove my application from list of installed packages? I haven't installed it via dpkg or apt-get, but with adobe air installer, so I don't need it to be registred in dkpg

However I have adobeair package:

```
dpkg --list |grep adobeair
ii  adobeair            2.5.1.17730           Adobe AIR 2
```

And still apt-get says:

```
 someapp.a1909296681c7acefe45687d3a64758c8659bf46.1 : PreRequire: adobeair (>= 2.0.0.0) but it can't be installed
```

Above line was in other language and I translated it to english, so original text can be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to uninstall the manually installed version and then [download this deb](http://ubuntuone.com/p/euK/) and install it. (Packaged by prakash advani [here)](http://cityblogger.com/archives/2011/02/25/64-bit-adobe-air-for-ubuntu)

Comment: I have the Canonical Partner Repository enabled, but it seems to not include adobeair package for Ubuntu 10.10 (64 bit version), so I can't install it like in your answer.

Comment: didn't notice the 64-bit.edited and included the 64-bit deb.

Comment: Thanks, I already found [this blog post](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/tech/2010/02/22/better-adobe-air-beta-2-package-for-ubuntu-64-bit-jaunty/) and it works. Solution provided in your links looks similar, so I accept your answer. Thanks!